# Select data from two different tables of two different database in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

There are three tables 'TA' and 'TB' two belong to same database but the third table 'TC' belong to other database. I need to fetch the last row from the third table 'TC' and based on the data obtained in the last row i have to fetch all the data from 'TA' and 'TB'. Please help me for this as there are two database.
Structures of the tables:
TA(id, usrId) TB(fk_usrId, deviceId, version) TC(version)
Need to select all the deviceId having latest version. Latest version is stored in the last row of the TC table.

Comment: post the sample data and Output what you want

Comment: MySQL or sql-server? they have different methods

Answer (score 1):

`select ta.id,ta.userid from ta join tb on ta.userid=tb.usrid join tc on tc.version=tb.version and tc.version=(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tc ORDER BY version  DESC)`
here im selecting last column based on no then given desc based on ur need use the sub query.that must be unique

Answer (score 0):

**In SQL Server if the two databases reside in the same server**

```
SELECT * FROM FirstDB.Schemaname.TA INNER JOIN FirstDB.Schemaname.TC ON TA.userid = TB.user id and TB.version IN (SELECT TOP 1 version FROM SecondDB.Schemaname.TC ORDER BY version DESC)
```

**In SQL Server if the two databases reside in different servers**

Then you will have to add one server as a linked server in the other and use the server qualifier also in the above query

linked server reference link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188279.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this for SQL Server:

```
select ta.*, tb.*
from 
(select top 1 version from differentdb..tc order by version desc) t
inner join tb on tb.version = t.version
inner join ta on ta.id = tb.fk_usrId
```

Try this for MySQL:

```
select ta.*, tb.*
from 
(select version from differentdb.tc order by version limit 0,1) t
inner join tb on tb.version = t.version
inner join ta on ta.id = tb.fk_usrId
```

Comment: You have received some nice answers. To give closure to your question, please mark one of the answers as accepted assuming it has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

First You need to add linked  servers in server objects and then write the table name like [ServerInstanceName].[databasename].[schemaName].[TableName]
for both tables follow the above syntax in the FROM Refference of query 
Rest of the code will be normal